# JAX-RS/Glassfish: Secure requests based on session attributes

Tags: jax-rs, glassfish-3

I am trying to enable security mechanisms having a security schema not depending on the default authentication model.
The given model has a Session attribute (User) which might be checked for permission via

```
user.hasProjectAccess(String prjId)
user.isAdmin()
user.hasRole(RoleTypes.BASIC)
```

Now, having this user in my session scope I want to use this mechanism in my REST-Model knowing that in fact REST-services should not have session context. My JAX-RS Bean is stateless and injecting and thus session is not an option.

How can I introduce security into my system? I could programmatically add a token (userToken) to my data request, perform a db lookup for this token and would have the user entity in this case.

But this is not really an option. Do you have any ideas how to handle this?